From the spinor metric to the Pauli exclusion principle
I am attempting to teach myself Quantum Field Theory.   Using two books by Schwichtenberg, "Physics from Symmetry" and "No-nonsense QFT" I have learnt that one can take the inner product of two Weyl spinors through the use of the second Pauli matrix (which could then be multiplied by i to make it real).
Critically this shows that for any Weyl spinor $|a>$  you get $<a|a>=0$.  Does this not, therefore, prove the Pauli exclusion principle?
I'd love it if this really simple idea derived, arguably, a principle underlying the whole of chemistry.  And yet when I look elsewhere I read that a proof of the Pauli Principle is incredibly difficult to achieve.  Indeed according to one article in Wikipedia:

"An elementary explanation for the spin–statistics theorem cannot be given despite the fact that the theorem is so simple to state. In the Feynman Lectures on Physics, Richard Feynman said that this probably means that we do not have a complete understanding of the fundamental principle involved"

Would appreciate any comments.

Apologies.  I've just found a very similar question posted 7 years ago, therefore there is no need to respond.   Peter
